# Cannot assign to <method name> because it is a method group: Error (Using Moles framework)

Tags: c#, moles

These two lines of code give me the error as mentioned in the title. I am trying to define a stub for `TestClass`

```
var stubTestClass = new StubsTutorial.Moles.STestClass();
stubTestClass.WriteStuff = () => "Moled in static class!";
```

And this is how the function WriteStuff() is defined

```
public class TestClass {
  public string WriteStuff() {
    return "Stuff written in main class.";
  }
}
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. And direction would help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [a tutorial](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/molestutorial.pdf) I found:

> Each mole type is named by prepending an “M” to its name
>   and placing it into a .Moles namespace.

So maybe your line

```
var stubTestClass = new StubsTutorial.Moles.STestClass();
```

should be changed to

```
var moleTestClass = new StubsTutorial.Moles.MTestClass();
```

though I have no experience with Microsoft Moles.

Comment: Yes. The stub generated is a partial stub and hence non-virtual members cannot be instantiated there. The option is to use Moles. Thanks.

Comment: @TheSilverBullet The important thing to be aware of is if `WriteStuff` is still just a method inside the Moles class you consider, or if it has been converted into a property of delegate type, namely a property of type `Func<string>` in this case (representing the method with zero parameters and return type `string`). I think `STestClass` (the "stub" version) works by having the delegate in a specially named field (probably called something with `WriteStuff`). The method `WriteStuff` is then still a method, which means you can pass the stub `STestClass` to a method you're testing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Moles user but...

"By default, stubs are generated for all interfaces and abstract classes, although you can also configure Moles to generate stubs for non-abstract classes that expose virtual methods"

So

a) have you configured correctly
b) I note the method is not marked virtual if a) is correct

i.e.

```
public virtual string WriteStuff() { ... }
```

because enclosing class is concrete (not marked abstract or interface)

Comment: This is related to the Moles framework. STestClass is the stub defined for TestClass. Please notice the tags.

Comment: can you define which line exactly gives you the error? it is either one or the other not both. I reckon it is the second...

Comment: and see other answer relating to the naming convention used by Moles when creating the test classes

Answer (score 0):

Stubs create their fake delegates for public abstract and virtual methods by overriding them. If the method is not marked virtual or abstract, any attempt to assign the stub delegate with a value will be overruled by the compiler because the method was not overriden to return an assigned delegate. Try it by stubbing a test class with two methods, one simply public and the other public virtual. In order to test a public class with no interface contract or abstract or virtual methods, shims must be used, not stubs.